# request.user.group returns auth.Group.None for Django custom user model

Tags: python, django

Created custom user model, initially without PermissionsMixin, then realized, that I will need it, and added. Makemigrations, migrate - done.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
[..]
```

Solution, works partially.
I can add user to the group, db is updated, can see the relation, but user.groups returns None.
What am I doing wrong? How to troubleshoot it?

```
    for group in Group.objects.filter():
        print(group, group.id)    
    request.user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(id=2))
    print(Group.objects.get(user=request.user))
    print(request.user.groups)
```

gives output:

```
individual_customers 1
business_customers 2
staff 3
business_customers
auth.Group.None
```

Answer (score 1):

Django permission Groups are many-to-many relations, so you need to call them like so:

`request.user.groups.all()`

It should return a queryset with all the group permissions that are related to the user